# Assigning MATLAB ANN Inputs/Outputs

Tags: matlab, neural-network, classification

I have a problem with setting up a Neural Network in MATLAB in a Data Classification problem where my data is labelled. I have 6 separate problems I wish to diagnose - each problem has a matrix with data inside it (50x60). Initially I had hoped to have a 6 bit output matrix going high for each corresponding classification problem however I am struggling to get this to work.

I am struggling to assign a target to train the network - regardless of whether I leave the input as a cell array or actual values I cannot get the tool to deal with the different output sizes. My question is what would the best 'target' structure be to classify the different problems? I had thought binary initially, however assigning descriptive diagnosis a numerical value can be challenging.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you edit your post to include some example code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I did understand correctly but in general lets assume we want to perform binary or two-class classification.

**What we have?**

We have two arrays arraycls1=50X60 and arraycls2=50X60 each consist of 50 exact features for 60 samples for class one and two.

**What is next?**

You should concatenate both arrays into one:

```
datatotal=horzcat(arraycls1,arraycls2);
```

Your output should be an array of size 50 by 120 saying that you have 50 features for 120 samples.

**How to create *target* array?** 
To do we use an array: `target=zeros(NumOfCls,NumOfSmpls)` in our case NumOfCls=2 and NumOfSmpls=120. Now you should populate target in appropriate order:

```
target(1,1:60)=1; //class 1
target(2,61:120)=1; //class 2
```

Thus length of your input and target arrays will be kept the same and you should perform your classification.

Hope this helps!